# onClickListener for disabled edittext not called

Tags: android, eclipse, android-edittext

I am trying to capture when an edittext field which is disabled gets pressed.
(I only want to change it, I dont want text inserted into it).
I assigned an onClickListener to it but it is not called.. Any suggestions ?
Is there any other event I can listen to ?

```
final EditText field = column.get(i);
field.setEnabled(false);
field.setClickable(true);
field.setFocusable(false);
field.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

field.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((EditText)v).setText("a");

            }
        });
```

Thanks !

Comment: `setClickable(true)` is called in `setOnClickListener`, and the handling of `setFocusableInTouchMode`  is done in `setFocusable`. So those two lines are not really necessary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cant pass a click-event when a `View` is disabled.

Therefore, try changing:

```
field.setEnabled(false);
```

To:

```
field.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: try now with my updated answer. make sure you have set `field.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);` which will not allow your EditText to raise soft-keyboard

Answer (score 1):

```
final EditText field = column.get(i);
field.setCursorVisible(false);

field.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                field.setText("something");
                field.clearFocus();
            }
        }
    });
```